# states and capitals 2d array, java

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array, states

here are my requirements:

> Create (hard coded) the 50 states and their capital cities, using a 2
>   dimension array.
>
> In the dialog box: ask the user either to enter the State or a City.
>
> If the state is entered, find its capital city. If a city is entered,
>   find its State.
>
> If not, found, issue an error message.
>
> This should be in a Loop, until the user does not want to play
>   anymore.

I really don't know where to start, all I have done so far is create the array, I don't really get how to search the array, and spit out the corresponding state/capital.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Here is the code I have written so far.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class GuessStates {
    public static void main(String[] args){

          java.util.Scanner input = new java.util.Scanner(System.in);

     String[][] statesAndCapitols = {
        {"Alabama","Alaska","Arizona","Arkansas","California","Colorado","Connecticut","Delaware","Florida","Georgia","Hawaii","Idaho","Illinois","Indiana","Iowa","Kansas","Kentucky","Louisiana","Maine","Maryland","Massachusetts","Michigan","Minnesota","Mississippi","Missouri","Montana","Nebraska","Nevada","New Hampshire","New Jersey","New Mexico","New York","North Carolina","North Dakota","Ohio","Oklahoma","Oregon","Pennsylvania","Rhode Island","South Carolina","South Dakota","Tennessee","Texas","Utah","Vermont","Virginia","Washington","West Virginia","Wisconsin","Wyoming"},
        {"Montgomery","Juneau","Phoenix","Little Rock","Sacramento","Denver","Hartford","Dover","Tallahassee","Atlanta","Honolulu","Boise","Springfield","Indianapolis","Des Moines","Topeka","Frankfort","Baton Rouge","Augusta","Annapolis","Boston","Lansing","St. Paul","Jackson","Jefferson City","Helena","Lincoln","Carson City","Concord","Trenton","Santa Fe","Albany","Raleigh","Bismarck","Columbus","Oklahoma City","Salem","Harrisburg","Providence","Columbia","Pierre","Nashville","Austin","Salt Lake City","Montpelier","Richmond","Olympia","Charleston","Madison","Cheyenne"}};

            System.out.println("Please enter a State or a capitol city.");
                String userInput = input.nextLine();



        }
    }
```

thanks again!

Comment: I really start by reading some of the basic java tutorials on looping mechanisms, as a hint a do...while loop would probably be the simplest option for the input. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/while.html and a for loop for the searching algorithm http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/for.html

Comment: I understand everything on those pages, understand how to search a numeric array, I don't know where to start with strings though.

Comment: oh ok, well your best bet would be to loop the whole array, and on each pass check both the State and the capitol using String.equals function. Remember that as strings are complex objects the "==" is not always correct, Inside the loop if you find the state print the capitol, if you find the capitol print the state. Hope this helps, Note searching an array is the same regardless of array type

Comment: thanks, I'll see what I can come up with.

Comment: cool let me know how you get on, if you have a problem with the code post and i'll take a look

Comment: Little tiny nitpick: "Capitol" (with an o) is the building where the legislature or Congress meets.  The city is a "capital".  Common error, though.  The Java compiler won't catch this :) :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try searching through the array with a for loop.

Using a for loop it keeps track and updates your current position of traversing the array.

Once you find the correct state or capital (by checking if userInput.equalsIgnoreCase(statesAndCapitols[x][y]), then take the current position you are at and retrieve the information needed.

I.E.

```
for(int x = 0; x < 2; ++x) //loop through states the first time, capitols the second
  for(int y = 0; y < 50; ++y) //always 50, unless new states get added (obviously not a problem in this example, but useful to think about in future problems - YOUR DATA WILL ALMOST ALWAYS CHANGE.
   if(userInput.equalsIgnoreCase(statesAndCapitols[x][y])
      System.out.println(statesAndCapitols[x == 1 ? 0 : 1][y]);
```

In the array, I did x == 1 ? 0 : 1.  That's a ternary operator, what it's saying is if x is equal to 1, use the value 0, otherwise use the value 1.

That's one way to go about this problem.

Another way would be to create your own Class/Datatype for the cities and states, that way you don't need to keep your arrays *in sync*, meaning you don't need to update 2 items for one change (like add another city/state combo).

Hope this helps a bit! :)

Comment: perfect. I can't believe it was so simple, I was over thinking it, by a lot.

thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
String entered_state=input.nextLine();
for(int i=0;i<50;i++){
    if(statesAndCapitols[0][i].equals(entered_state)){
        String searched_city=statesAndCapitols[1][i];
        //print the city name
        break;
        }
}
if(i==50) 
//print error
```

Same thing for searching state from entered city.

Comment: The way the original array is initialized (which is different than how most people would do it), you've got the indexes of the 2-D array in the wrong order--should be `statesAndCapitols[0][i]` and `statesAndCapitols[1][i]`.

Comment: so I should have done 50 rows and and 2 columns, instead of 50 columns and 2 rows? is that what you mean?

Comment: yes, thats the general idea.In your code, you're making two sets of 50 elements each,linked one-one.The other way, you'd be making 50 sets of a pair of state & city.

Comment: @ryan5892 The best way would be to make a 1-D array where each element is an object that contains both the state name and the capital, instead of a 2-D array.  If this is for a class, it's possible you haven't learned how to do that yet.

Comment: @ajb
It had to be a 2d array, but yea I know it would be more simple that way, thanks.